# Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. on SSMS on my PC

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I get this error on the SSMS on my PC. This procedure has Linked server.

> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

But if I try the same by remoting on the server and run on the SSMS there it works fine.

Comment: If you're using windows authentication then this sound like you have a double hop issue. Talk to your network administrator about this and they'll know how to configure it.

Comment: Or configure the linked server to use SQL Authentication.

Comment: The linked server is setup as "Be made using the login's current security Context". Why it won't work SSMS on my PC? Every time to run these procedure I have to remote into the SQL Server and run from the SSMS on the Server.

Comment: This might be a better fit on [dba.se]